# React - Invalid hook call problem for authentication

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I use token authentication for my react spa app. I'm trying to add a token using React hooks.

I have a three file for this small example.

1. AuthContex.js
2. AuthReducer.js
3. authentication-service.js

When user click on the login button, react call authentication-service.js in login function.
When the user is logged in, I need to register the token into the state with the help of hooks. Because, I need to refresh the token at any point in the application, and as a result of this refresh the token was not distributed correctly to all components. I thought of solving this problem by placing the token on top of all components. Thus, if the token is refreshed at any time in the application, it would be distributed properly to the subcomponents.

**But react has gave the error** --->>

> × Unhandled Rejection (Error): Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be
>   called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen
>   for one of the following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such
>      as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

```
function login(username, password) {
    const { authDispatch } = useContext(AuthContext);
    return axios.post('/api/Authentication/SignIn', {
        email: username,
        password: password
    })
        .then((res) => {
            // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes

            localStorage.setItem('auth-jwt', JSON.stringify(res.data));
            currentUserSubject.next(res);

            authDispatch({ type: LOGIN, payload: res.data });
            return res;

        }).catch(handleResponse);

}
```

Please see my [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-nash-eljq5) for a small demo.

Comment: useContext is a hook and must be called in a Reactjs component. How are you calling the login function in your app?

Comment: @DavidLee forexample, authenticationService.login(username, password).then(() .....) you can see on my sandbox

Comment: You can't use `useContext` outside of a ReactJs component.  If login needs to have access to the context, that function should go inside some component instead of off on its own

Comment: @CoderDeneme your codesandbox does not have any code that calls your authenticationService#login method. How is this being called in your component?